# How can I change the Data that I got from my Database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I get my data out of my db with the following code:

```
private void fillData() {
        cursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllSubjects();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.KEY_TITLE, DatabaseAdapter.KEY_LECTURER, DatabaseAdapter.KEY_BEGIN };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.lecturer, R.id.time };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter subjects = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.subject_row, cursor, from, to);

        setListAdapter(subjects);
    }
```

Now my problem is, that I want to add 3 other columns from my db and want to get the following:

- "("+DatabaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE+") "+DatabaseAdapter.KEY_TITLE
- DatabaseAdapter.KEY_LECTURER
- new Date(DatabaseAdapter.KEY_BEGIN)
- new Date(DatabaseAdapter.KEY_END)
  --> these two should be in one TextView in the way dd.MM. HH:mm (this is from BEGIN) - HH:mm (this is from END)

I don't know how I'm able to do that - please help me :)

Comment: I think you'd get better response if you make the question a little clearer. Nobody wants to spend time guessing what the rest of your code looks like or what you are struggling with. :)

Comment: What do you mean with the rest of my code? I don't know surely what code you are interested in?!

Comment: I'm just not sure what the problem really is. Is your cursor not containing all the fields? If so, you need to show us the source code for fetchAllSubjects() i suppose. Is the problem getting the data from the cursor into the layout, you should probably show us the layout.

Comment: No no all the things you said works fine, but I don't know how I can transform the data I got from the database before I put them in the layout.. So I get the Begindate as a long - how I can transform that Integer to a date before I put it in my layout. Do you now know what I mean??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out what you really wanted.

Instead of using "SimpleCursorAdapter" directly, you can create your own Cursor adapter, inside which you can mainipulate the data as you want.
Create a new Adapter "SubjectsAdapter.java". In this Adapter you will override the "bindView" and "newView". This allows us to apply a view to the cursor. But before doing so, gives us the opportunity to change the data from the cursor.

This will give you an idea what has to be done.

```
    private void fillData() 
    {
        cursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllSubjects();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);


        SubjectsAdapter subjectsAdapter = new SubjectsAdapter(this, cursor);
        setListAdapter(subjectsAdapter);
    }


//SubjectsAdapter.java - make changes to fix bugs/compilation errors. This is untested.
public class SubjectsAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter 
{
    public SubjectsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cur) {
        super(context, R.layout.subject_row, cur);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
         LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         return li.inflate(R.layout.subject_row, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {           
        TextView titleText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
          titleText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));

        //You can add code to retrieve other columns here.

        //This is where you retrieve the date in long format from cursor, convert it to a required format, and then using it.
        TextView beginTimeText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time);            
        Long lBeginDate = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapter.KEY_BEGIN));
        String sBeginDate = getFormattedDate(lBeginDate);           
        beginTimeText.setText(sBeginDate);
   }

    private String getFormattedDate(Long lDate)
    {
         SimpleDateFormat smdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");       
        String sDate = smdf.format( lDate ));
        return sDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh I think that is not the right thing, because my db has got the following columns: ID, Type, Title, Lecutrer, Room, Begin (not as a Date --> it's converted with getTime()), End (thats the same as at Begin).. And now I've got a TwoLineListItem with 3 TextViews.. my first TextView should get the Text of my first point, the 2nd should show me the 2nd point and the last TextView should show the Date which I describes at my last point.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you know a solution for my problem? Do you think I need to make a individual cursor?

Comment: @Prengepower I have changed my answer based on your comments "So I get the Begindate as a long - how I can transform that Integer to a date before I put it in my layout. Do you now know what I mean?? ". Please see the answer above.

Comment: Yeah okay that's no problem - my problem is that I don't know where I should use it. I get the cursor with all my data and put this one in my SimpleCursorAdapter - so I don't know where I can change these data..

Comment: @Prengepower Figured out what you really wanted. Updated my answer.Instead of SimpleCursorAdapter, create your own Adapter(see code). over ride the "bindView" and "newView" methods. I have added a sample code to do it. Hope this helps.